# Effective Approaches to Testing Private Methods in Flutter Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, testing

I'm looking for the most effective way to test private methods in Flutter when writing unit tests. The methods that I want to test are meant to be private, and I'm searching for an approach that's both clean and less likely to cause issues in the future. Currently, I'm aware of a few methods, but none of them feel entirely satisfactory. Could someone suggest a better alternative or provide insight into which option is more reasonable and less likely to lead to complications down the line?

Here are the methods I've considered:

1. **'part' and 'part of' Directives:** This involves writing 'part - partof' for each class in all unit tests. However, I find this approach cumbersome and not very practical for my needs.
2. **meta Package by dart.dev:** Leveraging the 'meta' package developed by dart.dev: This package includes an annotation called '@VisibleForTesting'. While using this annotation, a warning is issued advising that the method should only be used for unit testing purposes. Nevertheless, it's important to note that this annotation only serves as a warning and doesn't enforce access restrictions.
3. **dart:mirrors or reflectable Library:** Utilizing 'dart:mirrors' or the 'reflectable' library for Dart reflection: I haven't used this approach before, as I've heard it can negatively impact code readability and performance.

Comment: If the private functions are used inside public functions, then you could test a part of the public function that covers the private function.

Answer (score 1):

Use both `@protected` and `@visibleForTesting` on a "public" method, either in place of the original private method, or as a parallel access.  Sure, it's only a lint that can be ignored, but most sane developers pay attention to every lint.